# Issue with lighting, possibly normal related?

Tags: opengl, shader, lighting, normals

I'm using OpenGL 3.3 and having some odd lighting issue, I'll first show two screenshots at different angles and then give the shader code.

First angle:

[image: first angle]

Second angle:

[image: second angle]

What you see here is:

- A cube, with its middle on the origin;
- A directional light source, coming from the yellow point through the origin;
- In cyan you see the normals of the vertices.

I know the normals of the vertices are "wrong", but I was exactly trying to debug those.

What I expected was: A (from top-to-bottom) varying color of every face, depending on the position of the "sun" and the camera.

But what I get is that two parts of the cube (upper and lower) that both have varying colors, but not in the way I expected.

There is code for shadows in the shader, but I deliberately disabled them here to avoid confusion.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 model_matrix;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 view_matrix;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 shadow_matrix;

out VS_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
    vec4 shadow_coord;
} vs_out;

uniform vec4 light_pos = vec4(-20.0, 7.5, -20.0, 1.0);

void main(void) {
    vec4 local_light_pos = view_matrix * light_pos;
    vec4 p = view_matrix * model_matrix * position;

    //normal
    vs_out.N = normalize(normal);

    //light vector
    vs_out.L = local_light_pos.xyz - p.xyz;

    //view vector
    vs_out.V = -p.xyz;

    //light space coordinates
    vs_out.shadow_coord = shadow_matrix * position;

    gl_Position = proj_matrix * p;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
    vec4 shadow_coord;
} fs_in;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2DShadow shadow_tex;

uniform vec3 light_ambient_albedo = vec3(1.0);
uniform vec3 light_diffuse_albedo = vec3(1.0);
uniform vec3 light_specular_albedo = vec3(1.0);

uniform vec3 ambient_albedo = vec3(0.0, 0.2, 0.0);
uniform vec3 diffuse_albedo = vec3(0.2, 0.7, 0.2);
uniform vec3 specular_albedo = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
uniform float specular_power = 128.0;

vec3 rgb_to_grayscale_luminosity(vec3 color) {
    float value = color.r * 0.21 + color.g * 0.71 + color.b * 0.07;
    return vec3(value);
}

void main(void) {
    //normalize
    vec3 N = normalize(fs_in.N);
    vec3 L = normalize(fs_in.L);
    vec3 V = normalize(fs_in.V);

    //calculate R
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    //calcualte ambient
    vec3 ambient = ambient_albedo * light_ambient_albedo;

    //calculate diffuse
    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0.0) * diffuse_albedo * light_diffuse_albedo;

    //calcualte spcular
    vec3 specular = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), specular_power) * specular_albedo * light_specular_albedo;

    //apply shadow and write color
    float shadow_value = textureProj(shadow_tex, fs_in.shadow_coord);
    if (shadow_value > 0.0001 || true) {
        //no shadow
        color = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        //in shadow
        //color = vec4(rgb_to_grayscale_luminosity((ambient + diffuse) * (1 - shadow_value)), 0.5);
        //color = vec4(vec3(shadow_value), 0.5);
        color = vec4((ambient + diffuse) * (1 - shadow_value) * 0.5, 1.0);
    }
}
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: from the shots, it's clear that the problem is the normals not the shader. for such simple geometry, you should list the normals and show how you compute them

Comment: @a.lasram The normals are visible in the shots.

Comment: as you mentioned in your question these normals aren't good. instead of shaders you should show the code that setup the normals and the geometry. the bug is likely there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your normals only point upwards/downwards (x=0 and z=0 in the OpenGL coordinate system) what you see should be the expected behavior (no bug concerning the shaders/graphics pipeline).

During the rasterization stage in the graphics pipeline the attributes are interpolated among the vertices (barycentric coordinates).
Assuming that all normals above the plane "y=0" are

- "vec3(0, 1, 0)"

and all normals below this plane are

- "vec3(0, -1, 0)"

then for every pixel the interpolated normal will be

- "vec3(0, *, 0)" where * is >0 above the "y=0"-plane and <0 below that plane.

In your fragment shader you normalize all normals hence they will all again be

- "vec3(0, 1, 0)" if the corresponding vertex lies above the "y=0"-plane and
- "vec3(0, -1, 0)" if the corresponding vertex lies below that plane.

This will result in the same color for all vertices below and above the "y=0"-plane.

You could check this if you would remove the normal-"normalization" within the fragment shader or if you add a minimal offset to the x- or z-coordinate of some normals e.g.

- vec3(0.0000001, +/-1, 0)